# horizontal infinite scroll (carousel)

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I would like to ask for help in knowledge about how to make a responsive horizontal infinite scroll (carousel) with content.

Functionally I like how Anders Drage has done it: [example](http://andersdrage.com/)

How it smoothly scrolls infinitely as a carousel. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? I tried out endless.js, but I can't get that to function correctly.

Comment: That page just resets back to it's original position once you hit a certain position on the page. You just need a placeholder on the page that triggers a function when it comes into view.

Comment: Hmm.. I have to look more into that then through it feels like a carousel

Comment: Look at the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the page. You'll see it reset itself.